# type specific amount of characters

Tags: c++

I'm new to coding with C++ and currently listening to an online coding lecture and I have to make a program that calculates the divisors of the inputted number and output * as the divisor numbers.

ex) if I input 8 the divisor is '1 2 4 8' and the final output shoul be '* ** **** ********'

I have made it so it calculates the divisors but can't figure out the next part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d", &a);

    if(a<0, a>1000)
    {
        printf("Number must be in the range of 0~1000"); //set the range of the input number
        exit(0);
    }   

    for(b =1; b<=a; ++b)
    {
        if(a%b==0)
        printf("%d ", b); //calculate the divisors
    }

    // the next part of the code which I can't figure out

    return 0;
}
```

I have made it until here.

Comment: thats c code not c++

Answer (score 0):

Use a another for loop inside if statement like this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b,c;
    scanf("%d", &a);

    if(a<0 || a>1000)
    {
        printf("Number must be in the range of 0~1000"); //set the range of the input number
        exit(0);
    }   


    for(b =1; b<=a; ++b)
    {
        if(a%b==0){
        printf("%d ", b);//calculate the divisors
        for(c=0;c<b;c++){ //for loop to print stars
            printf("*");
        }
    }

    }

     //the next part of the code wich I can't figure out

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that for loop is not really idiomatic c, should really be 'c=0; c< b; c++'

Comment: You may want to also fix `if(a<0, a>1000)` while at it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(b =1; b<=a; ++b)
    {
        if(a%b==0){
     // printf("%d ", b); //calculate the divisors
        for ( int i = 0; i < b; i++ ){
             printf("*");
         }
          printf(" ");
        }
    }
```

You calculate the divisors, which is b

if input is 8, the b will be 1 2 4 8

so you can use b as a for loop stop condition.

Then, the output is:

b = 1：*

b = 2：**

b = 4：****

b = 8：********

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I edited it. English is not my native language too.